# the root of $N$th transpose matrix

Tags: matrices, roots, transpose

For $n=3,$ $L$ matrix is as below:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&1&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

for $n=4$ we have:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0\\
-1/3&-1/3&-1/3&1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

and for $N$th we have:
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& & \vdots&\vdots\\
-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&\cdots&1&0\\
-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&\cdots&-1/(N-1)&1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

How to get the roots (eigenvalues) of the $N$th order of the $L+L^T$ matrix? is there a specific logic between the roots of this matrix?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you be clearer?

Comment: What roots do you mean? Can you give them for the 3x3 case?

Comment: By "roots", do you mean eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes! i mean eigenvalues of that.