# eigenvalues of $N$th transpose matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

For $n=3,$ $L$ matrix is as below:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&1&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

for $n=4$ we have:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0\\
-1/3&-1/3&-1/3&1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

and for $N$th we have:
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& & \vdots&\vdots\\
-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&\cdots&1&0\\
-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&\cdots&-1/(N-1)&1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

How to get the eigenvalues of the $N$th order of the $L+L^T$ matrix?

Comment: How is this any different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3547504/265466)? If you’re simply changing “roots” to “eigenvalues,” then you should simply edit that one.

Comment: @amd anybody can't answer that question, so i ask in another way. Can you help me?

Comment: The characteristics polynomials are easy to calculate, as the determinant of a triangular matrix

Comment: No, you didn’t “ask in another way.” This question is identical to the previous one, and you’ve even _deleted_ a few things along the way.

Comment: @Damien i don't have enough experience. Can you help me how to calculet the relationship between eigenvalues of this matrix?

Comment: @amd ok, what's the problem? If i delete my previous question, can you help me to solve this?

Comment: All of these matrices have $(1,-1,0,\dots)$ as an eigenvector with eigenvalue $3$, but the rest of the eigenvalues are going to be ugly.

Comment: @amd Sorry I can't follow you. The characteristic polynomial is equal to $(1-x)^n$. What remains is to calculate the multiplicity...

Comment: @Damien The OP is asking about the eigenvalues of $L+L^T$, not of $L$. Finding the eigenvalues of the latter is of course trivial since it’s triangular. It’s also pretty easy to work out the geometric multiplicity of the lone eigenvalue of $L$, but that’s not the matrix in question.

Comment: @amd My bad. I read too fast. Sorry

Comment: @Damien yes, question is about $L+L^T$ matrix.

Comment: @amd yes, i know that thay are going to be ugly :( Do you have any idea to find the relationship?